# Custom MIME Types with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, restkit

I've been banging my head against a wall around which methods in RestKit to pick to fulfill what I'm trying to achieve.

I have been given an API specification that requires me to POST and object in JSON format with a custom MIME type and then receive the updated JSON representation of that object and deserialize it.

I have tried simply using [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:customobject delegate:handler] however I can't get this to use anything except form encoding.

I then tried `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectLoaderForObject:customObject method:RKRequestMethodPost delegate:handler]` and setting the serialization MIME type to `@"application/json"`. This works for serializing the object as JSON but doesn't help with the custom Content-Type.

Using the second method above, I tried implementing the `HTTPHeaderValueForContentType` message but this never seems to be called and the params object is an NSDictionary.

From there I've tried adding the custom MIME type the Parser Registry using the same logic as `[RKParseRegistry autoconfigure]` but I feel that I'm digging deeper into hack territory with every step.

The problem with this approach too is that it doesn't help my "Accepts" header, it is still "`application/json`".

Below is some specification about the REST API I need to consume (with some keywords changed)

NB: [I have cross-posted this on the RestKit Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/browse_thread/thread/261f59ad17797ba3)

---

```
Request POST /customobject/ HTTP/1.1
Accepts application/vnd.company.customobject-v1+json
application/vnd.company.customobject-v1+xml
Content-Type    application/vnd.company.customobject-v1+json
Sample content  {
  "type"      : "type-a",
  "direction" : "left",
  "listofitems": [
    { "itemnumber": "123"}
    ]
}


Response    HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type    application/json
Location    /customobject/[id]
```